# What is the Pandas Equivalent of SQL Update?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This has to be really easy but Google isn't helping. What is the Pandas/Python3 version of:

```
UPDATE table
SET column1 = 'value'
WHERE column2 LIKE 'some value%'
```

UPDATE: Sorry, it's more than just update. It's update with a wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`pandas.Series.str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
df['column1'] = np.where(df['column2'].str.startswith('some value'), 'value', df['column1'])
```

`np.where` works as follows: `np.where(condition, value if true, value if false)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.startwith` here , this is just condition assign with basic `.loc`

```
df.loc[df.column2.str.startswith('some value'),'column1']='value'
```